# erro FacebookOperationCanceledException no jogo exemplo do Facebook SDK Friend Smash

Tags: java, android, facebook

Segui o [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial) do Facebook SDK para implementar o jogo [Friend Smash](https://github.com/fbsamples/android-friend-smash). Na activity Home tem um botão para visualizar os Scores. Porém ao clicar ele apresenta um erro de conexão na tela:

> Please check your network connection -- erro de FacebookOperationCanceledException

Antes disso ele já estava logado ao usuário, e apresentou sem problemas o nome e a foto após aceitar o pedido de permissão do jogo no meu facebook.

No log.cat ele apresentou o seguinte erro:

> 01-31 13:25:36.791: E/FriendSmash(5312): org.json.JSONException: Value false of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONArray

Buscando solução, encontrei as seguintes linhas que onde aconteceu o problema. A string `getURL` retorna `FALSE`.

```
// Get the attributes used for the HTTP GET
String currentUserFBID = application.getCurrentFBUser().getId();
String currentUserAccessToken = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();

// Execute the HTTP Get to our server for the scores of the user's friends
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String getURL = "http://www.friendsmash.com/scores?fbid=" + currentUserFBID + "&access_token=" + currentUserAccessToken;
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);

// Parse the response
HttpEntity responseEntity = responseGet.getEntity();
String response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
JSONArray responseJSONArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

Uma dúvida inicial é se esta url é criada automaticamente, pois o exemplo já traz o `http://www.friendsmash.com/`, porém não setei isto quando criei o aplicativo no *Facebook developer*. Este aplicativo já existe no Facebook, isso pode causar conflito?

Alguma solução? O código está igual ao baixado do tutorial e segui o tutorial para a criação de novo aplicativo no *Facebook developer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas perguntas:

1. Você está executando uma versão recente do tutorial? Procurei no GitHub pelo código postado, e não encontrei em lugar nenhum (nem no `friendsmash_complete` nem no `friendsmash_incomplete`). Se seu código for uma revisão mais antiga, é possível que a API tenha mudado.
2. O seu usuário de teste permitiu **tanto** a sua app **quanto** a app do Friends Smash (não sei qual é, nem sequer se tem uma, mas acredito fortemente que sim)? E se sim, você chegou a postar algum *score* antes de tentar lê-los?

   Resolvi testar a URL do tutorial, e ao passar meu User ID e um [Token de Acessso temporário](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1331462558?fields=id,name), também recebi como resposta `false`. Tentei também postar um score para ver se isso resolvia o problema (fazendo um `POST` com meu `fbid`, `access_token` e um `score`), e recebi a seguinte resposta: "No user with fbid 1331462558 found". Procurei no restante do tutorial um meio de me registrar, mas não encontrei.

   <sub>(achei [esse aplicativo](https://apps.facebook.com/friendsmashsample), que *parece* o sample do Friend Smash, mas resolvi **não dar permissão** pra ele me mandar e-mails nem publicar no meu nome só pra responder uma pergunta no SOPT, sorry!)</sub>.

   Ou seja, acredito que a razão dele estar retornando `false` é porque ou você não está registrada e/ou porque nunca postou um score. Seus parâmetros estão corretos (caso contrário você veria uma mensagem de erro) e são válidos (caso contrário você veria `null`), daí concluo que o `false` faz parte da lógica do site `friendsmash.com` mesmo, não me parece ser nada de errado que você tenha feito não...

Na minha opinião, essas são as causas mais prováveis do seu erro (a 2ª mais que a 1ª), pois:

> Uma dúvida inicial é se esta url é criada automaticamente, pois o exemplo já traz o http://www.friendsmash.com/, porém não setei isto quando criei o aplicativo no Facebook developer. Este aplicativo já existe no Facebook, isso pode causar conflito?

Creio que não é preciso (e talvez nem possível) setar isso dessa forma, pois a função do servidor segundo o próprio tutorial é "postar e buscar *scores* do seu próprio servidor para criar um *scoreboard*".  O `friendsmash.com`, se ainda ativo, deve fazer apenas isso, sem exigir qualquer integração adicional do seu aplicativo com ele. Repare nas seguintes linhas:

```
String currentUserAccessToken = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();
...
String getURL = "http://www.friendsmash.com/scores?fbid=" + currentUserFBID + "&access_token=" + currentUserAccessToken;
```

Quando você faz isso você está **dando seu *User Access Token* para ele**, e como [os tokens são portáveis](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#portabletokens), isso é tudo o que o `friendsmash.com` precisa para agir no nome do seu usuário (i.e. ler e modificar dados dele). Desnecessário dizer que isso é um problema de segurança (agravado pelo fato do token ser passado via `GET` sem o uso de `HTTPS`), mas no contexto do problema específico significa que não falta nada para o site do Friend Smash agir.

Nota: o token dá tanto acesso quanto ele tinha quando foi criado; por exemplo, quando fiz aquele teste anteriormente, garanti que o token só seria válido por 60 minutos e não dei permissão alguma além das mais básicas (ver meu nome, foto e lista de amigos). No seu caso, me parece que você está extraindo o token concedido **à sua app** e repassando ele **ao `friendsmash.com`**, de modo que ele terá as mesmas permissões que sua app tem. Nesse caso específico, não creio que haja nada malicioso, mas na prática é bom tomar bastante cuidado com o que um token contém antes de compartilhá-lo com outros sites (pois isso afeta diretamente a privacidade **dos seus usuários/clientes**).